# How do I get my do while loop to work in C?

Tags: c, do-while, cs50

I'm new to programming and even newer to the C language so please be nice.... I'm currently working on a problem which requires me to take the input 'height' and print a triangle of the appropriate height. The height cannot exceed 8 or go below 1, so I have implemented a do while loop that will reprompt the user for height if it exceeds the 1 - 8 range. The problem is: my code will take the input even if it exceeds the the range. Here is my code so far.... If someone could tell me how I'm being stupid, I'd really appreciate it.

```
#include <cs50.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

int get_height(void);
int lineno;
int column_fill;
int main(void)
{
    int height = get_height();
    for (lineno = 1; lineno <= height; lineno++ )
    {
    for(column_fill = 0; column_fill < lineno; column_fill++)
    {
    printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
}

int get_height(void)
{
    int height;
    do
    {
        height = get_int("Height: ");
    }while(height < 1 && height > 8);

    return height;
}
```

Comment: `height` can't be both `< 1` AND `> 8` so the test is always `false`. I suggest `while(height < 1 || height > 8);`

Comment: One stylistic note: you should always indent for every curly brace you open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `||`, which means "or". The height can never be less than 1 *and* greater than 8, but it can be less than one *or* greater than 8.

Comment: Thank you wise one.